# How do I add Linux capabilities SYS_NICE and DAC_READ_SEARCH to container in AWS Fargate?

Tags: aws-fargate, linux-capabilities, ecs-taskdefinition

I'm trying to setup a task definition in ECS Fargate for running Koha containers but Fargate won't accept

`--cap-add=SYS_NICE --cap-add=DAC_READ_SEARCH`

(or any other kernel capabilities except for `SYS_PTRACE`) in the [task definition json file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html). I tried adding  `"linuxParameters": {"capabilities": {  "add": [   "SYS_NICE", "DAC_READ_SEARCH"],`to the task definition json file but Fargate simply deletes the code.
The mpm_itk module fails without this option (and my container throws an 500 error with the following warning/error in the logs

`[mpm_itk:warn] [pid 17146] (itkmpm: pid=17146 uid=33, gid=33) itk_post_perdir_config(): setgid(1000): Operation not permitted`

How do I work around this? Is there a way to pass on these capabilities after the container has started up? Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to [AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_KernelCapabilities.html)  Fargate only allows you to add the SYS_PTRACE kernel capability. It is not possible to add any other capabilities at the moment. The only viable workaround that I can see working is to use ECS EC2.

Answer (score 0):

The container created by docker runc is bounded by capability flag i.e.

> 0x00000000a80425fb=cap_chown,cap_dac_override,cap_fowner,cap_fsetid,cap_kill,cap_setgid,cap_setuid,cap_setpcap,cap_net_bind_service,cap_net_raw,cap_sys_chroot,cap_mknod,cap_audit_write,cap_setfcap

The container can get the capabilities from this set only.